# If my father had a day off, "we always went/would go" to see my grandfather

Tags: conditional-constructions

**If my father had a day off, we always went to see my grandfather.**

Is the sentence above grammatically correct?

I thought there should be **would go** instead of **always went** whether it's a past habitual action or a hypothetical statement.

Am I wrong? Can you please explain?

Comment: The sentence is grammatically "correct", in that its meaning would be understood by any native English speaker, and most would see nothing amiss in it. However, it is more usual to use the modal _would_ in conditional clause constructions like this one. When you say it "_should_ be **would go**", please understand that there is no "rule" that prevents the sentence from being written as it is, or brands it as a violation of some kind. (On the other hand, if the conditional clause were headed by _when,_ the simple past _went_ would be expected.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Does the meaning change, if I replace _always went_ with _would go_? Does the sentence given imply a hypothetical statement or a past habitual action?

Comment: It would be proper to replace _went_ with _would go._ The adverb _always_ can stay. That would be a fine substitution, and the meaning will not change; as it is, _always went_ conveys the same sense of habitual action as _would go_ (but not the sense of a hypothetical statement here.) The substitution of _would go_ is the more "proper" way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your example. Past subjunctive (action conditional, possible, wished for) has the same form as the simple past for all verbs except 'to be'.

You can use a conditional clause instead if you want to, but there is no compulsion.

Comment: 1. _If my father had a day off, we always went to see my grandfather_. 2. _If my father had a day off, we would always go to see my grandfather_ 3. _If my father had a day off, we always used to go to see my grandfather_. Can you please explain the _difference in meaning_ of the three sentences?

Answer (score 0):

If my father has a day off, we always go to see my grandfather.

The sentence expresses a habitual situation in the present

We can express this situation in the past as follows:

If my father had a day off, we always went to see my grandfather.

But it will be more appropriate if you replace if with when.

If my father had a day off, we would always go to see my grandfather.

It's usually considered a hypothetical sentence expressing an unreal situation in the present; there's no question about it.  I think to make it a habitual situation in a clear way, you use when instead of if as follows:

When my father had a day off, we would always go to see my grandfather.

Comment: Do you mean _If my father had a day off, we would always go to see my grandfather_ doesn't imply habitual action?

Comment: I think it will usually be considered as hypothetical; conditional type 2